# How to call a javascript function before and after button click event call in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

i have created "ButtonClick" function in ASP.NET as following:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="button" CausesValidation="true" onclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

i want to know, is it possible to call a javascript function before and after calling asp.net button click function...???

Thanks.

Comment: i want to show a div before calling asp.net function.

Comment: @Amir: Sometimes someone does not have time for research and has to submit task at very short notice. So pleases do not discourage someone from asking a question next time. Please maintain a healthy environment. Thank u.

Answer (score 15):

Yes it's possible, here is quick example:
Java script function to call.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function clientValidate() {
        alert("execute before");
        return true;
    }

    function executeAfter() {
        alert("execute after");
    }
</script>
```

Here is snapshoot for button

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="clientValidate()" onclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

Notice property onClientClick="clientValidate()", it will be trigger script before button click on the server.

On the server side:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "none", "<script>executeAfter();</script>", false);
        }
```

Notice executeAfter();, it will trigger javascript execution after server event.

Don't forget to place `<asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>` in your aspx file.

Hope it help

Answer (score 4):

put this on your page and make sure you have a scriptmanager. these codes will handle your pre & post postbacks.

```
var prm, postBackElement;
if (typeof Sys != "undefined") {
    prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
    prm.add_initializeRequest(InitializeRequest);
    prm.add_endRequest(EndRequest);
}

function InitializeRequest(sender, e) {
    postBackElement = e.get_postBackElement();
    if (postBackElement.id == "btnLogin") {
        // before click codes
    }
}
function EndRequest(sender, e) {
    if (postBackElement.id == "btnLogin") {
        // after click codes
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Before:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeBefore() {
        alert("execute before");   
    }
</script>

<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CausesValidation="true" OnClientClick="executeBefore()" onclick="btnLogin_Click"/>
```

After:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function executeAfter() {
        alert("execute after ");    
    }
</script>
```

Add this code to your server side event:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "none", "<script>executeAfter();</script>", false);
```

If you don't have a master page, or are not using ajax, there is no need to add ScriptManager.

Answer (score 2):

You can call Java scrip function before server side click using `OnClientClick()`:

**aspx(design)**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Test() {
            alert('client click');
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button Text="btn" runat="server" ID="btn" 
                        OnClick="btn_Click" OnClientClick="Test()" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**.cs**

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    Response.Write("Server Click");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

First time you can call your javascript function in Button's OnClientClick event passing your function name.

```
<asp:Button ID="btnLogin" runat="server" Text="Login" CssClass="button" CausesValidation="true" onclick="btnLogin_Click" OnClientClick="return functionNAME();"/>
```

Second time, in your button click event btnLogin_Click call js as follow

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), "script", "<script type='text/javascript'>functionNA();</script>", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

For calling it before, you could consider using onload function, like this example:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
```

For calling it afterwards, just link the button to execute JS onClick?

I don't think I quite understand your intentions.